# AWS VPC - Private subnet added to the public route table attached to internet gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Hope you are all doing good.

AWS allows us to attach a private subnet (created in a Customer VPC) with a route table having route to the internet via internet gateway. Does it make any difference to the instance launched in the private sub-net?  or it is as good as having the private subnet not linked to the route table having route to the internet

Regards
AJ

Comment: Can you described what are you actually seeking to accomplish? Or are you just asking out of interest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subnet is not private if it has routes to/from the internet. The instances launched in a private subnet cannot access the internet and cannot be reached from the internet.

For e.g if you have a database instance and you don't want anyone but the instances to access the instance, you can launch the instance in the private subnets.

Also if you want the instances in the private subnet to access internet, you need to setup a Nat Gateway (or a Nat Instance)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. How about this use case. Create a VPC -> Add a private subnet to it -> Create an internet gateway and attach it to the VPC -> Create a route table with access to the internet -> Attach the private subnet to the route table. The question is, why does AWS allow us to attach a private subnet to a route table with route to internet? I understand the concept that we need a NAT gateway (to access internet from within private subnet).

Comment: @Hadooplearner *"why does AWS allow us to attach a private subnet to a route table with route to internet?"*  Because "private" isn't an actual attribute of a subnet that the VPC service is aware of, it's simply a conceptual description of a condition defined by the entries in the subnet's attached route table.  Changing the associated route table or changing the table's routes is how you make a subnet either private or public.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot. Thanks. My recent observation is slightly different though. I have checked that, If the subnet is private (I am referring to "Auto Assign Public address" being set to no (unchecked)), all the EC2 instances launched inside the subnet never get access to internet as they are never assigned a public. This happens regardless of  private subnet's association status with a public route table i.e. a private subnet has only one way(NAT) if it has to access the internet. Hence, my doubt still remains as to why AWS allows us to attach private subnets to public route table.

Comment: @Hadooplearner disabling "auto assign public address" is done on private subnets but that setting does not make a subnet private, it simply causes VPC not to assign public IPs to instances launched in that subnet, which isn't the same thing.  You might also disable that option on a public subnet where you are exclusively using Elastic IP addresses and don't want the instances to ever have public addresses that you didn't attach, yourself.  VPC has zero knowledge of whether a subnet is public or private, so it lets you use a route table containing whatever your needs dictate.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense to me now. Definitely learnt a new thing. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to know what's the difference between a public subnet and a private subnet.



Public Subnet means this subnet has an `Internet Gateway` attached to it.
Private Subnet means this subnet has a `NAT Gateway` attached to it.

And the Internet Gateway can have both inbound and outbound but the NAT only can have outbound to the Internet.

**And A NAT will be built in a public subnet but attach to a private subnet.**



You can have lots of public/private subnets at the same time and attached NAT or IGW for them, but the IGW only can have one in each VPC.

In some use cases, we will not attach any kinds of NAT and IGW for a subnet. that's because it might be a database subnet and won't expect it to communicate with the Internet.
Normally, we will use a subnet with NAT attached for our application such as EC2 or ECS, Internal Load Balancers.
On the other hand, we will use a subnet with IGW attached for Internet-facing Load balancers, Nginx, Apache.

AWS VPC Design:
https://aws.amazon.com/tw/answers/networking/aws-single-vpc-design/

Comment: Thanks David. I understand the response. I created a a new VPC and added a private subnet to it. Then, I added a route table with access to internet and attached the private subnet to the route table. what difference it makes to the instances launched in the private subnet as they cant be accessed via internet. Why does AWS allow us to attach the the private subnets to the route table providing access to the internet.

Comment: Also, I have checked that every instance launched in a public subnet is automatically accessible from internet if the security group is configured properly. I dont understand the role of having a route table and internet gateway created when the instances in the public subnet can access internet even with out the route table.

Comment: @Hadooplearner if that is what you seem to be seeing, then you're making an observational error, somewhere. If an instance is on any subnet whose associated route table does not have a static route to the Internet (typically a default route, for destination 0.0.0.0/0) then that instance cannot access the Internet.  The only exception is that the instance can still do DNS lookups in that case, because VPC has some built-in magic for handling DNS lookup traffic.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot. Thanks. yes that was my mistake. While trying a few things again I did realize my mistake and observed exactly what you have just explained above. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the hidden magic here is that the instance in the private subnet needs a public IP to communicate with outside, we never ever think this an issue in our lives. When our computer connect to the router, it get access to internet without any issue, why it works so smoothly? All because the router handles everything for us, including allocating a private IP for us, making recursively DNS query for us, and the most important, translating the private IP using the router's public IP so that our computer can communicate with the outside bidirectionally.

Let's go back to this AWS VPC scenario, you attached a route table with a default route to the Internet Gateway to your private subnet, which makes it looks like a public subnet. However, the instances still have no public IPs,  and, not like our router, the Internet Gateway of AWS VPC doesn't do NAT works! So how can an instance with no public IP and no NAT access the internet? It's impossible.